# Spring Transactional annotation with readOnly don't apply (+Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, transactions

We are using Transactional annotation on an abstract service class and applying `readOnly=true`.
We expect all inheritance classes will enforce readOnly for their public methods, but in reality, we manage to do write operations on DB.

The idea was to prevent tables locking for transactions that do not write to DB so to allow faster multi-connections execution.

We are using Postgress with Jdbc connection.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, timeout = DEFAULT_OLTP_TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT)
public abstract class AbstractTransactionalOLTPServiceImpl<N extends Number, T extends PersistentOLTPEntity<N>> {
```

Comment: Postgres won't lock anything if you are only doing read queries. Readers never block writers and writers never block readers in Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an issue with `@Transactional` inheritance.
I couldn't reproduce it on my environment.
Could you provide information about usage of `AbstractTransactionalOLTPServiceImpl` in you code?

Also take a look at https://coderanch.com/t/714204/frameworks/Spring-Transactional-inheritance and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24291